# eclipselink: generate entities without joins

Tags: java, eclipselink

Two entities:

```
Customer <--- Account
 id             id
 name           customerId (FK to Customer)
                balance
```

eclipselink 'generate entities from tables' generates the two entity classes. `Customer` has reference to `Account` and vice versa.

```
public class Customer {
  Integer id;
  String name;
  Account account;
}

public class Account {
  Integer id;
  Customer customer;
  Double balance;
}
```

Required: Generate entities with relationship attribute as basic type instead of Entity name:

```
public class Customer {
  Integer id;
  String name;
  Integer accountId; // <-- this is id instead of Account
}

public class Account {
  Integer id;
  Integer customerId;  // <-- this is id instead of Customer
  Double balance;
}
```

Why we need this:
`Customer` and `Account` are managed by separate applications and hence packaged in separate wars. Each war may potentially be deployed on a separate app server. If the Customer application needs Account details, it will use the public API provided by Account application and does not read from DB directly. This is to avoid Customer application from modifying the Account entity by itself without the knowledge of Account application.

Eclipselink generation has an option to turn off relationship generation altogether. Is there a way to generate only the ids instead of entity class names? Or is there a better way to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd manage this differently.  For this answer I assume you're using the Eclipse feature to generate the entity classes? Generally I only do this once and if something changes touch it up by hand.  That just seems easier to me.  It also avoids Eclipselink being too smart for its own good - which sounds like what you're suffering from.

Design wise I guess you want the close coupling of a foreign key without the implied effect of data linking.  If you don't define the *Table Association* Eclipselink will just generate native types for your columns.  This of course loses the database based coupling of foreign keys.  That could be particularly problematic if your database has Cascading turned on.

Honestly this smells a little more like a "who owns the data" problem than strictly a programming one.  Perhaps your problem would be better addressed by Service layer classes you can all agree on?  Or maybe they will publish @NamedQueries you could include?  Finally there's always Stored Procedures in the database itself - these are generally a source of great frustration but security people love them.